# Overlap ImageIcons on a JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, overlap, imageicon

I'm developing a GUI of a game in Java Swing: the frame of the boardGame is a GridLayout, and in every cell there is a JButton. The cell has an attribute "height" from 0 to 3, and if i click in a button i want to increment that height. 
In particular i want to overlap the previous imageIcon on that JButton (setted with .setIcon("image.png"))  with another transparent imageIcon of the next layer (thus, the next height), in order to give visually another height.

something like this:
[image: something like that]

In the class that creates the boardGame:

```
 battlefieldPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,5));
        for(int j=4; j>-1 ; j--){
            for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
                //here i create a button for every cell
                buttons[i][j] = new CellButton();               //a class that extends JButton
                buttons[i][j].setCell(new Cell(i,j));
                buttons[i][j].setSize(100,100);                 //imageIcons are already 100x100 pixels
                buttons[i][j].setBorderPainted(false);   
                buttons[i][j].setContentAreaFilled(false);      //give transparency to the button
                buttons[i][j].setIcon("level0.png");            //initial image of height 0
                buttons[i][j].getCell().setHeight(0);
                battlefieldPanel.add(buttons[i][j]);
                buttons[i][j].addActionListener(new ButtonHandler(buttons[i][j], pics));
```

In the class that handle the click on the CellButton:

```
public class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {                                           
[...]                                   
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   incrementHeight();
}

public void incrementHeight() throws CellHeightException, ReachHeightLimitException, IOException {

      JLayeredPane jlp = new JLayeredPane();
      SpringLayout lpLayout = new SpringLayout();
      jlp.setLayout(lpLayout);

        if (button.getCell().getHeight() == 0) {

            ////////FIRST TRY//////////
            URL urlBG = new URL("url1");
            URL urlFG = new URL("url2");
            final BufferedImage imgBG = ImageIO.read(urlBG);
            final BufferedImage imgFG = ImageIO.read(urlFG);

            final BufferedImage combinedImage = new BufferedImage(
                    imgBG.getWidth(),
                    imgBG.getHeight(),
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB );
            Graphics2D g = combinedImage.createGraphics();
            g.drawImage(imgBG,0,0,null);
            g.drawImage(imgFG,0,0,null);
            g.dispose();

             button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(combinedImage));

            /////////SECOND TRY//////////////
            BufferedImage bigIcon =  ImageIO.read(new File("level0.png"));
            BufferedImage smallIcon = ImageIO.read(new File("level1.png"));
            BufferedImage finalIcon = new BufferedImage(bigIcon.getWidth(), bigIcon.getWidth(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics g = finalIcon.getGraphics();
            g.drawImage(bigIcon,0,0,null);
            g.drawImage(smallIcon,0,0,null);
            button.add(new JLabel(new Imagecon(finalIcon)));
            g.dispose();

            //////THIRD TRY//////////
            JLayeredPane jlp = new JLayeredPane();
            SpringLayout lpLayout = new SpringLayout();
            jlp.setLayout(lpLayout);
            JLabel l0 = new JLabel(pics[0].getIcon()) ; //l0.setBounds(0,0,100,100); 
            l0.setOpaque(true);
            JLabel l1 = new JLabel(pics[1].getIcon()) ; //l1.setBounds(0,0,100,100); 
            l1.setOpaque(true);
            jlp.add(l0);
            jlp.add(l1);
            lpLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, l0, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, jlp);
            lpLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, l0, 0, SpringLayout.SOUTH, jlp);
            lpLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, l0, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, jlp);
            lpLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, l0, 0, SpringLayout.EAST, jlp);
            lpLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, l1, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, jlp);
            lpLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, l1, 0, SpringLayout.SOUTH, jlp);
            lpLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, l1, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, jlp);
            lpLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, l1, 0, SpringLayout.EAST, jlp);
            button.setOpaque(true);
            //jlp.add(button);
            button.add(jlp);
            jlp.setVisible(true);

            button.getCell().incrementHeight();   //ai the edn i call the real method that handles the backend
        }
```

Comment: Check out the [Compound Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/compound-icon/) which allows you to combine two or more Icons into a single Icon.

Comment: It is good that you post the code in which your problem occurs. But please try to keep the code to the absolute minimum needed to describe the problem. Here you might for example just post the code for modifying one button.

Comment: Your first two tries look correct to me.  What’s wrong with them?

Comment: I wish i knew  it just doesn't appear anything on the button on the first click